# Do subtasks inherit the queue of their parent task?

Tags: python, celery

When creating a subtask (i.e. chord, chain, group) with Celery, and you have a multiple queues (i.e. high priority, low priority), does the subtask inherit the routing parameters of the task who created it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question having actually read the source...

### Short answer

No.

### Long answer

Tasks instantiated with `mytask.s()` and `mytask.si()` call [`celery.app.Task.subtask()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/task.html#Task.subtask) (called `signature()` in master), which does not set any routing information. Compare this to [`retry()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/task.html#Task.retry) which calls `subtask_from_request()`, which sets the queue from [`request.delivery_info`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#context).

### My Solution

Subclass Task to add the queue to `Task.subtask()`.

```
class Task(CeleryTask):
    """
    Override the Celery Task baseclass to send subtasks to the same
    queue as the main task.
    """

    def subtask(self, args=None, kwargs=None, options=None,
                *starargs, **starkwargs):

        kwargs = kwargs or {}
        options = options or {}

        # override the queue if not passed in as an option
        if set(('queue', 'exchange', 'routing_key')) & set(options.keys()):
            options.update(self.request.delivery_info)

        return super().subtask(args, kwargs, options,
                               *starargs, **starkwargs)
```

Use by passing `base=Task` to `@task`/`@shared_task`.

Answer (score 0):

In a word: No.
The task will use the routing as documented [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html)

Comment: Is there a canonical way of making sure subtasks are put into the same queue without knowing the queue of the parent task?

Comment: no, there is no one true way. depending on the specifics of your routing configuration there may be a way - consider posting a new question which shows your routing configuration and tasks